# WCF REST Service - Variables with backslash

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, url

I have the following contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Devices/{*id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Device GetDevice(string id);
```

The id of a device can contain backslashes "\" and "&" since it represents a path for a device.

When I send a GET request with the id, the GetDevice function receives the id, but with slashes "/" instead of backslashes "\".

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Is it an encoding issue? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ suggests that an id of `test1\test2&test3` should be encoded `test1%5Ctest2%26test3`.

Comment: I guess it's not an enconding issue. When passing `test1%5Ctest2%26test3` it receives `test1/test2&test3` :/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx) about how special characters in entity keys passed to WCF services can be handled.

Of note in your case is that turning off request filtering does NOT prevent the backslash from getting mangled:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0"/> 
<pages validateRequest="false"/>
```

Slashes and question marks are problematic because the underlying URI parser is unescaping the original URI...here's the workaround for those three characters:

```
<configSections> 
    <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
</configSections> 
<uri> 
    <schemeSettings> 
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/> 
        <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/> 
    </schemeSettings> 
</uri>
```

(also blatantly stolen from the article.)